# Why is CMake removing some include directories from INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES() calls?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, include, cross-compiling

We are trying to cross compile a certain piece of software and for most cases it has been working. However, the include files are split over multiple directories and, if the directorie lies outside the sysroot tree, sometimes CMake decides not to add it to the include list on Makefiles.

The toolchain is:

- GCC 4.4.1 for ARM (windows executables)
- MinGW Make (No MSYS)

The CMake call is as follows:

```
cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain-vde.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\vf-install ..
```

The `toolchain-vde.cmake` file is:

```
# the name of the target operating system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

# which compilers to use for C and C++
include(CMakeForceCompiler)
#Use 8.1 names if path has spaces since it will break on paths with spaces
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/VDE/toolchains/windows/vos/arm-vf-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-vf-linux-gnueabi-gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/VDE/toolchains/windows/vos/arm-vf-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-vf-linux-gnueabi-g++.exe")

# here is the target environment located
SET(VF_SYSROOT "C:/VDE/SDKs/vos/default")


#Vf includes and libs
#Declared as variables for compatibility and usage by CMake scripts down the line
SET(VF_ADK_INCLUDE       "C:\\VDE\\ADKs\\default\\vos\\include")
SET(VF_ADK_LIB           "C:/VDE/ADKs/default/vos/lib")
SET(VF_SDK_USR_LIB       "${VF_SYSROOT}/usr/lib")
SET(VF_SDK_USR_LOCAL_LIB "${VF_SYSROOT}/usr/local/lib")
SET(VF_SDK_USR           "${VF_SDK_USR_LIB}") #<-- Compatibility with old Vf detection
SET(VF_SVCMGR            "${VF_SYSROOT}/usr/local/lib/svcmgr")

MESSAGE("debug1: --- ${VF_ADK_INCLUDE} --- ${VF_SYSROOT} ---")

SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${VF_SYSROOT}")

#Define variables for compiler and CMAKE scripts
set(VF_UX_410 TRUE)
add_definitions(-DVF_UX_410="${VF_UX_410}")

LINK_DIRECTORIES("${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lrt --std=gnu99")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lrt")

LIST(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${VF_ADK_INCLUDE}")
```

Notice the last line, `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${VF_ADK_INCLUDE}")` this directory, `VF_ADK_INCLUDE`, if it exists, **will be ignored during build**. Meaning that the `make` call will not have the `-IC:\VDE\ADKs\default\vos\include` argument but if the directory is not there, the makefiles **will have** the proper `-I[...]` argument.

If I add the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` such as:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  "X:\\"
  "C:\\VDE\\ADKs\\default\\vos\\include"
  "Y:\\"
)
```

Both `X:` *and* `Y:` will appear on the compiler call as `-IX:\ -IY:\` but somehow the middle include is missing. Doubly Oddly, if I rename the include directory during config (so cmake cannot find it), then rename it back during compilation, CMake has added the correct `-I[...]` argument and the program compiles just fine.

As a workaround, right now I'm hardcoding the `-I[...]` argument on the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variables but this solution is far, far, far from correct.

*edit:* the `MESSAGE` call shows the correct path/value during CMake configuration. So it shouldn't be a "variable is not defined" issue.

In essence and to make this a proper question:
***Why does CMake remove or ignore include paths from `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` calls?***

Comment: Good, detailed question! But why are you setting `include_directories()` in the toolchain file? AFAIK, this is not the common [toolchain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) idiom. The [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) for `include_directories()` indicate that this call affects only the **current** directory and targets defined in the **current** file. But you don't add any targets in this file, from what you have shown...

Comment: The toolchain is part of a big ugly proprietary solution, so the headers are split over many directories inside and outside the system root (which is the preferred idiom AFAIK) so the `include_directories` on the toolchain has been used since all further CMakeLists.txt executed will inherit these includes. Unsure what the 'correct' way of doing this is.

Comment: Apparently CMake has some internal "exclusion list" and these directories are somehow excluded when they exist. Reference via: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17966  If no proper solution arises I will go with this one since "it works"

Comment: It may be placed on the exclusion list because it is specified in the toolchain file? Have you tried instead putting it in your top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: Yes, I did. using both `include_directories` and `target_include_directories` and the path gets excluded as well. It is likely that during the compiler detection it considers the compiler "knows" that path when it is not true, hence why disabling exclusion (ugly hack) works.

Comment: CMake actually removes include paths which are treated by the compiler as *implicit* ones. This is done for a good reason (as far as I remember, `#include_next` directives in the system headers could be broken if system include directory is added explicitly). But such removing shouldn't break things unless CMake detection fails, or your program requires such include directories to be explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days I couldn't find a better answer so I'll post this answer-to-self since it works.

During the compiler detection, CMake will extract a series of implicit include paths which usually are always available and, if added to include paths, might break the compilation process (Thanks to @Tsyvarev for the caveat). However, if this path gets incorrectly added to the excluded paths, the only way I could find to override this is removing the exclusion list alltogether using:

```
unset(CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
unset(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

As described on https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17966 but this solution is using CMake internals so it may do or break depending on your compiler or environment. In this particular case the fix worked.

On a similar situation, again with a proprietary + ancient gcc toolchain, simply updating to the latest CMake version worked, apparently due to better compiler detection.

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same problem seemingly completely randomly, and this was the only reliable way of fixing it. I have no idea how you found this solution. Note that I was buildinig RISC-V binaries using a GCC toolchain, and CMake was removing system includes that I specified in the toolchain.cmake file.

Comment: Why is anyone using cmake?   This is straight terrible.